# ValueError: continuous is not supported

Tags: machine-learning, regression, pandas, data-science-model

> I am working on a regression problem and building a model using Random
> Forest Regressor but while trying to get the accuracy I am getting
> ValueError: continuous is not supported.

```
train=pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\DELL\OneDrive\Documents\BigMart data\Train.csv")
test=pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\DELL\OneDrive\Documents\BigMart data\Test.csv")
df=pd.concat([train,test])
df.head()
```

> [image: Blockquote]

> After Data Preprocessing and Visualization, I have tried to build the model :

[image]

Please help with the error

Comment: You are getting the error because accuracy only works/is only applicable to classification problems. Since you are have a regression problem accuracy is not an applicable measure of model performance, you could try a different measure such as MSE/MAE.

Comment: yes, there was a mistake. it's fixed. Thank you